# BroadcastReceiver components are not allowed to bind to services

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, text-to-speech

I am trying to Implement a BroadcastReceiver which is called when a Phone call is received. In the BroadcastReceiver i am trying to get the name of the contact from the contact's phone number and then initialize a TextToSpeech Object which narrates a specific message.

I am Getting  error "android.content.ReceiverCallNotAllowedException: BroadcastReceiver components are not allowed to bind to services". So what can i do to achieve the desired functionality. Here is the code below

```
public class IncomingCall extends BroadcastReceiver {


@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    try {
       // this.context = context;
        // TELEPHONY MANAGER class object to register one listner
        TelephonyManager tmgr = (TelephonyManager) context
                .getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);

        //Create Listner
        MyPhoneStateListener PhoneListener = new MyPhoneStateListener(context);

        // Register listener for LISTEN_CALL_STATE
        tmgr.listen(PhoneListener, PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_CALL_STATE);

    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("Phone Receive Error", " " + e);
    }

}
private class MyPhoneStateListener extends PhoneStateListener {
    Context context;
    TextToSpeech ttobj;
    MyPhoneStateListener(Context context)
    {
        this.context = context;
        ttobj = new TextToSpeech(context, new TextToSpeech.OnInitListener() {
            @Override
            public void onInit(int status) {
                ttobj.setLanguage(Locale.UK);
            }
        });
    }

    public void onCallStateChanged(int state, String incomingNumber) {

        Log.d("MyPhoneListener",state+"   incoming no:"+incomingNumber);

        if (state == 1) {
           // String msg = "New Phone Call Event. Incomming Number : "+incomingNumber;
            String name = getContactName(incomingNumber,context);
            String msg="";
            if(name=="")
                name = "Unknown Number";
            msg = "Sir, Incoming Call from "+name ;
            ttobj.speak(msg, TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, null);
        }
    }

    public String getContactName(final String phoneNumber, Context context)
    {
        Uri uri=Uri.withAppendedPath(ContactsContract.PhoneLookup.CONTENT_FILTER_URI,Uri.encode(phoneNumber));

        String[] projection = new String[]{ContactsContract.PhoneLookup.DISPLAY_NAME};

        String contactName="";
        Cursor cursor=context.getContentResolver().query(uri,projection,null,null,null);

        if (cursor != null) {
            if(cursor.moveToFirst()) {
                contactName=cursor.getString(0);
            }
            cursor.close();
        }

        return contactName;
    }
}
}
```

Comment: I suggest that you edit your question and post the entire Java stack trace.

Answer (score 1):

Create a `Service` in your app (it will need to be a foreground service) which is started by your `BroadcastReceiver` to do the work. In your service you will be able to query the contact into and trigger the text to speech.

Comment: *it will need to be a foreground service* - why?

Comment: Otherwise there is no guarantee it will remain running, especially on newer versions of Android, due to power management and resource handling.